# How to improve speed on a Razor page with expire headers and Gzip compression?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, gzipstream, expires-header

When testing my website on tools.pingdom.com I get a warning that I should compress components with Gzip and also that I should add expires headers. I have set Common headers in IIS to 7 days, but this does not seem to help. Is there a programmatic way to set this?

Comment: I added this code, but does not seem to make a difference:

 Response.Headers.Append("Expires", DateTime.Now.AddDays(30).ToUniversalTime().ToString("R"));

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression